# Activity disapear in emulator

Tags: android

I created an activity which has a button and a text view, but when I run my emulators, my text view and my button is not shown.
It has a warning message also that system UI is not responding.

I set graphic to hardware and did some setting, and again my activity is disappearing.

Comment: Can you provide the message you've gotten?

Comment: Are the other apps in the emulator working?  If so, there could be a problem in your app, so it would be helpful if you could post the code in your activity.